# Request timeout while pinging App domain in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have created a separate domain for configuring App on my SP 2013 server. when I am pinging this domain it says "request timeout". Any kind of suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Request Timeout is mean there is a `network issue` between SharePoint Server and new Domain ,

[image]

- Make sure you are typing the Domain Server IP at `Ping command` correctly.
- Ask the network administrator to check the network connectivity between two servers.

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas. I am using the command "ping spApps.com". spApps.com is the forward lookup zone, that i have created in DNS.

Comment: Dear are you tried to use IP instead of FQDN at ping command

Comment: Yes... i tried using the IP assigned to spApps.com but its same. However I can ping the IP of DNS server.

Comment: so the issue in configuring DNS , try to check it with the system / network administrator ? I tried to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The post is made a year back and I think by now you've resolved it.I was facing the same issue.For me these steps worked :

1. Open Network and Sharing Center : Click on your connection ->
2. Properties ->Select Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IpV6) ->
3. Click Properties -> Select "Use the following DNS server address":
   and mention ::1-> OK -> OK .

[image: Use the following DNS server address]

4. Now try to ping your app domain like this : ping
   anything.collabapps.com .

[image: ping your appdomain]

It should return the ipv4 address of your machine .